# Run a symfony application in apache webserver

Tags: apache, symfony, virtualhost

I need to run a symfony application on an apache server.
I created the file nameofmyapplication.localhost.conf with the following code:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
</ Directory>
<Directory / opt / lampp / htdocs / docsandparcels / public />
    Options -Indexes + FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

</ Directory>
<VirtualHost *: 80>
    ServerName www.docsandparcels.localhost
    ServerAlias ​​docsandparcels.localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain1.com
    DocumentRoot / opt / lampp / htdocs / docsandparcels / public /

    ErrorLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /docsandparcels.localhost-error.log
    CustomLog $ {APACHE_LOG_DIR} /docsandparcels.localhost-access.log combined
</ VirtualHost>
```

the error is the 404 object not found when I try to log in with the following url: docsandparcels.localhost / public /
How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Your document root points to ".../public", so your URL with suffix "/public" will get mapped to ".../public/public".

Comment: Try using http://www.docsandparcels.localhost/

Comment: See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: I've already tried the official symfony documentation

Comment: if I write http: //www.docsandparcels.localhost/docsandparcels/public/login the application runs on the server

Comment: But you are not using virtualhost

Comment: Please post output of `sudo apachectl configtest`

Comment: So it works with `www` and doesn't work if you do not use `www`, is that right?

Comment: What's with all the spaces in the `documentroot` and `directory` paths?

Comment: with sudo apachectl configtest:

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Comment: Have you enabled `nameofmyapplication.localhost.conf` ? (sudo a2ensite nameofmyapplication.localhost.conf) and reload|restart apache ?